# When connect with HDMI the speed of video is faster then usual

Tags: 14.04, sound, hdmi, playback

My nb is ASUS K450J, when connect with HDMI the speed of video is faster then usual. How to fix it.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: why is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems  a known problem  that can be fix passing `i915.disable_power_well=0` as kernel parameter:  [link](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=74861)

To pass kernel parameter, look this very good [page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters).